# in Debian rescue shell: cannot resolve FTP/HTTP addresses

Tags: nameserver

After accidentally removing a package needed for DHCP, my Debian installation has lost internet access.

After rebooting from Debian-netinstall disk, and entering a rescue shell, the situation is as follows:

- ifconfig shows I have got an IP address
- ping to another computer in my LAN works
- apt-get sees my /etc/apt/sources.list
- but I cannot download the missing packages because addresses like ftp2.de.debian.org are not resolved.

Comment: What does `resolv.conf` contain?

Comment: Has been messed up during my rescue attempts. `/etc/resolv.conf` is a link to `/etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf`; `/etc/resolvconf/run/` is a link to `/run/resolvconf/`; but in my `/run` there is no `resolvconf`.

Comment: That sounds like the cause of the problem described in the question.

Comment: Thank you, Håkan: after removing the dead links `etc/resolvconf/run/` and `etc/resolv.conf`, I could create a new `etc/resolv.conf`, which solved the problem.

Comment: How shall we proceed to close this question?

Comment: Seeing as you have posted an answer yourself (which is fine) I think the only step left would be for you to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to comment by Håkan Lindqvist.

I conjecture that I created the problem by restarting the networking system from within the rescue shell.